# Build RemapValue table name in Python script and then access the Remap Table

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, reclassify

I have a bunch of rasters that need to be reclassified. I am not sure the best way to create RemapValue tables, but I made them in Excel. I then dumped them in the Python script and they are now hidden objects.

```
SiteA_remap = arcpy.sa.RemapValue([[1,100], [2,200]])
SiteB_remap = arcpy.sa.RemapValue([[1,10], [2,20]])
```

I can see them if I type `SiteA_remap`; the table will show up in the Python console.

But if try to build `SiteA_remap` like in the code below, `my_remap = 'SiteA_remap1'` and this will not bring up the remap table, just a string.

How do I call this Spatial Analyst object (remapTable) without typing the name in the console? Because if I type `my_remap = SiteA_remap`  it works and `my_remap` is a now a remapTable. How do I build the name and call it in my code?

```
import os, arcpy, arcpy.sa
from pathlib import Path

inputRasters = r"D:\FOO\BAR"

#list to hold rasters
fooList = []

for path, dirs, files in arcpy.da.Walk(inputRasters, datatype = "RasterDataset"):
    for f in files:
        fooPath = os.path.join(path, f)
        fooList.append(fooPath)
     
        thatName = Path(f).stem
        fooName = thatName.split("_",1)[0]
        
        inPath = os.path.dirname(fooPath)
        inDir = os.path.basename(inPath)
    
        #my_remap = os.path.join(inDirName + "_remap")
        my_remap = inDirName + "_remap" 
        # do more stuff
```

Comment: Example from help works like a charm.

Comment: Which "Example from help"?, I don't see a solution here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/spatial-analyst/remapvalue-class.htm Thanks

Comment: Scroll down the page.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a solution on the [RemapValue help page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/spatial-analyst/remapvalue-class.htm) for calling the `RemapValue` tables that I 'copied and pasted' into the Python environment (look like this `SiteA_remap = arcpy.sa.RemapValue([[1,100], [2,200]])`. I had tried to build the `RemapValue` table name within the Python script (e.g., `my_Remap = os.path.basename(inPath) + "_remap"`), but did not have success.

I have since become aware of Python dictionaries. Instead of dealing with the cumbersome process of creating the tables in Excel with a series of concatenations (which wasn't working the way I wanted as evidenced above), I built a dictionary where each each key was a site name, and the values for the key/value pair were arranged as a list of lists which is required by `arcpy.sa.RemapValue`.

```
my_Dict = {}

with open(r'D:\Foo\Bar\Foobar.csv') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  header = next(reader)
  rows = [header] + [[row[0], int(row[1]), int(row[2])] for row in reader if row] # site name, value1, value2
  
for row in rows:
    if row[0] in my_Dict:
        my_Dict[row[0]].append(row[1:])
    else:
        my_Dict[row[0]] = [(row[1:])]

# ...

checkInDir = os.path.join(inDir) # is the site name in the dictionary?
            if checkInDir in my_Dict:
                my_remap = my_Dict[checkInDir]
                
                outRemapped =  arcpy.sa.Reclassify(inFile , "VALUE", arcpy.sa.RemapValue(my_remap))
                outRemapped.save(r'D:\Foo\Bar\Foobar_Remapped.csv')
```